# Why is my basic PyGame module so slow?

Tags: python, pygame

I've planning on writing a code in Pygame and I was just getting started with the basics and found that the executing code was really slow. When I press a key it takes a while for it to print it in the terminal (there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it).

I'm running Python 2.6, I downgraded after coming across this problem. With further testing I've found that the **whole system slows down**. Has anyone come across this or got a solution so it runs faster or/and prevents the system from slowing down?

OS - Ubuntu 
Hardware - Macbook Pro

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals
pygame.mixer.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("bla")

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill(pygame.Color("green"))
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

looping = True
while looping:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            looping = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keyName = pygame.key.name(event.key)
            print "key pressed:", keyName

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print "Loading Music"
                pygame.mixer.music.load("born.mp3")

            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                looping = False

    pygame.display.flip()
```

If there's any further information I can provide I would be happy to help.

Comment: I've tested your code on my Ubuntu box, and I don't notice any delay between my keypress and the display. do you notice the delay after loading the mp3 ?

Comment: Even without the loading of the mp3 there is still a delay. I have used pygame in the past and have never had an issue like this. I would expect the same results as you. That's why I thought it might be something to do with the hardware/software combination.

Comment: What is your computer speed?  You basically have a while loop going non-stop which could be the reason your computer is bogging down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pyGame is based on SDL which is internally based on threads.

When you have threading, print messages are basically a no-no. Because often times because of the scheduler slices (which are large in SDL), the print messages get delayed. Its not that pygame is slow (it is some situations, but, not in this one), its just that the print statement is in a seperate event thread.

Try doing [this](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/performance/fishietank/) in pygame, it'll run pretty well.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, thanks. But in the past I have done the same thing and there have been no problems. It also seems to be slowing down the whole system so I'm not sure that this answer explains what is really going on in my case.