# How do I run a python script using a specific interpreter?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I'm having problems with pygame as documented here:
[PyGame bogging down linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158213/pygame-bogging-down-linux)

After a bit of searching around and brainstorming I realized it may be because I'm using python2.7 instead of 2.6 which PyGame was designed for.

How do I run my script using the 2.6 interpreter instead of 2.7 (which seems to be the default).

Thanks

OS - Ubuntu

Comment: Also shebang lines are worth it

Comment: good point, thanks. Sometimes I forget about these details, usually I miss that out but I can see now where it would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python installs different binaries (and links to binaries):

- `python` links to the system's standard Python (2) version
- `python3` links to the system's standard Python 3 version
- `python2` links to the system's standard Python 2 version
- `python2.7` is the Python 2.7 interpreter
- `python2.6` is the Python 2.6 interpreter

So just use it like this:

```
python2.6 file.py
```

Note that you need to have Python 2.6 installed of course.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `python2` link on Ubuntu?  I think there is `python` for the standard 2.x version (not necessarily the most recent one) and `python3` for the standard 3.x version (also not necessarily the most recent one).

Comment: Thanks! You went into more depth than was required and I appreciate that. Turns out that hasn't helped with my problem with PyGame but I'm sure I'll figure it out! :)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: There is one on the Ubuntu I use.

Comment: Ah, good to know :)  I asked for two reasons: 1. The [Ubuntu package contents search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents) gives a hit for `python3`, but not for `python2`.  2. On Debian `python2` does not exist, and Debian is similar to Ubuntu.

Comment: The `python2` name is a relatively new thing, brought on by Linux distributions that chose to make `python` be Python 3 (contrary to underpublished recommendations and expectations.) Older distributions are less likely to have it.

Answer (score 0):

First install the alternative Python using `apt-get` and second, run with full path to the interpreter.

Also, on ubuntu you should be able to use something like `python2.6 script.py`.